# How to move large history of a repository from one server to another?

Tags: git, git-history

I have a very large repository with a long history of changes. I have to migrate it from one server to another. The new server has a size limitation which I need to somehow solve. I want to move the repository with all of its history. But the history is to big so I wanted to split the history and upload each part separately. It should work but I'm not sure which git commands I should ran in order to split the history and upload each part. How can I do it?

Comment: Soudns like something you would use filter-repo for:

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: Can you explain in more details what the size limitations are ? total size on disk for the repo ? size per individual upload ? number of commits ?

Comment: number of commits up to 30.

Comment: 30 commits is not long. to clarify, this is what you want to keep, correct?

Comment: I want to keep the full history. The server allows only 30 commits :/ So I need to split it somehow

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a shallow clone. Then push that up to your new server.

```
git clone -–depth [depth] [remote-url]
```

If there is a specific branch you want and ignore the others, you can also do.

```
git clone [remote-url] --branch [name] --single-branch [folder]
```

But you have to ask yourself why is the history so large? And when you make the new copy, do you care about the same hashes? If, not, consider trimming the size of the repo with `git filter branch`